# Calculate date from months form

Tags: javascript, html

On my form, I have three fields.

1. Date of Issue
2. Validity Period (Months)
3. Expiry Date

I would like if you enter the date of issue and the validity period fields, The expiry date field to calculate and fill itself. How can I achieve this? The validity period may vary. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="tarehe" data-validate = "Date of Issue is required">Date of Issue
<input class="inputpekee" type="date" name="issue_date" placeholder="Date of Issue">
</div>                  
<div class="tarehe" data-validate = "Validity Period is required">
<input class="inputpekee" type="number" name="validity" placeholder="Validity Period(Months)" min="1" max="60">                     
</div>
<div class="tarehe" data-validate = "Expiry Date is required">Expiry Date
<input class="inputpekee" type="date" name="expiry_date" placeholder="Expiry Date">                     
</div>
```

I expect the format to be dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
let dateOfIssue = moment();
    
    let validityMonths = 48;
    
    let expiryDate = moment(dateOfIssue).add(validityMonths, 'months');
    
    let el = document.getElementById('expiryDate');
    
    el.innerHTML = expiryDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="expiryDate"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it without having to use moment, using setMonth

```js
$('#validity').change(function(){
  let dt = new Date($('#issue_date').val());
  dt.setMonth( dt.getMonth() + parseInt($(this).val()));
  let output = dt.getDate()+'/'+(dt.getMonth()+1)+'/'+dt.getFullYear()
  $('#expiry_date').val(output);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tarehe" data-validate = "Date of Issue is required">Date of Issue
<input class="inputpekee" type="date" id="issue_date" name="issue_date" placeholder="Date of Issue">
</div>                  
<div class="tarehe" data-validate = "Validity Period is required">
<input class="inputpekee" type="number" id="validity" name="validity" placeholder="Validity Period(Months)" min="1" max="60">                     
</div>
<div class="tarehe" data-validate = "Expiry Date is required">Expiry Date
<input class="inputpekee" disabled name="expiry_date" placeholder="Expiry Date" id="expiry_date">                     
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Damian, this code actually works the way i want when I run the snippet here on Stackoverflow but that's not the case when i paste the code in my file. What could I be doing wrong? is it a tag or should they be on different files...?

Answer (score 0):

No need any library JS can do this easy, just learn documentation :

get Date Value ( valueAsDate ) => https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

DateTimeFormat => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

example :

```js
const FormOption = { day: '2-digit',  month: '2-digit',  year: 'numeric' };

document.getElementById('My-Form').onsubmit = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  console.log('issue_date : ', new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR', FormOption).format(this.issue_date.valueAsDate) );
  
  console.log('expiry_date : ',new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR', FormOption).format(this.expiry_date.valueAsDate) );

}
```

```html
<form id="My-Form">
  <label class="tarehe" data-validate="Date of Issue is required">Date of Issue
    <input class="inputpekee" type="date" name="issue_date" placeholder="Date of Issue">
  </label>
  <label class="tarehe" data-validate="Validity Period is required">
    <input class="inputpekee" type="number" name="validity" placeholder="Validity Period(Months)" min="1" max="60">
  </label>
  <label class="tarehe" data-validate="Expiry Date is required">Expiry Date
    <input class="inputpekee" type="date" name="expiry_date" placeholder="Expiry Date">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">get Values</button>
</form>
```